# Certain Products not Showing in Catalog but Not in Search

Tags: catalog, products, search

My some products not showing in search. I attach the screen shots of the problem.

Please provide a solution. Thanx...[image]![image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HfpV.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Magento is provide a  setting to, a product is showing on `category page or search and both page or it not visible` in fronted buy using `visibility` attribute you n`eed check this by Store wise,if you have multiple Stores.`

[image]

Change the scope fro left side panel of product 
[image]

and ckd the 
visible in

`Catalog,Search`  or `Search`

.You may be Search Catalog for that means product is not visible search page.

If it is solved you issue then you need re-index from index management

Comment: Yep , it is resolved. I only do re-indexing, then its working..thanx...